# Intercept WEBrick request

Tags: ruby, http, rake, webrick

I have a web app that runs on different pieces of hardware, that for the most part consists of smart TVs and set-top boxes.

My web app contains a ruby script to setup the app for local debugging. This script builds my app, listens for file changes, and hosts the app using a simple WEBrick server.

Now I'm running into a problem on a specific piece of hardware. This hardware expects to get a success response from a POST request to a health_check API running on the same host as the web app, before it will load up the web app.

I'm simply hoping to intercept this request and spoof it so that the hardware will load my client. So far I've gotten as far as this:

```
def start_server
    require 'webrick'

    root = File.expand_path 'public'
    request_callback = Proc.new { |req, res| 
        if req.path =~ /health_check/
            # return 200 response somehow?
        end
    }
    server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 5000, :DocumentRoot => root, :RequestCallback => request_callback
    server.start
end
```

I can modify the response object to set status to 200, but it still ends up returning a 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to "intercept" all requests and check for a specific path. You simply want `mount_proc`, to handle a specific route with a proc.

Add the following before `server.start`:

```
server.mount_proc '/health_check' do |req, res|
  res.body = 'what what' # your content here
end
```

You'll probably want to wrap this in a check to determine if you're running on whatever custom hardware requires this behavior.

See [Custom Behavior](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html#label-Custom+Behavior) in the WEBrick docs.